# Closed, uncountable set without rationals.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cantor-set

Problem: Find a closed, uncountable without rationals,  subset in the unit interval.

Solution: Let X be any binary irrational number , replace the 1s with 2s in the decimal expansion .

Now we can use the digits of X as an index for a path through the cantor set, for example, if the first two digits of X are 0 2 then we take [0 , 1/3] and then we take [2/9 , 1/3] .

This subset is obviously closed and uncountable, and since we are using an irrational index all the elements of that subset will be irrational.

Ok, is there a big mistake here? And secondly, If all the end points of a cantor set are rational doesn't this contradict the above?

Comment: $[2,3]$ is closed, uncountable, and contains no rationals in the unit interval

Comment: What exactly is the subset in question - the intersection of the intervals you get from $X$? If so, that set has only one element.

Comment: Answer: yes, and yes. With your procedure, you'll get lots of those rational points (they aren't all endpoints, $1/4$ is in the Cantor set).

Comment: The procedure is to pick a third and throw the rest, and then pick another third of that and throw the rest and so on. You pick the thirds based on the digits of X

Comment: @Zee In that case you get only one point - e.g. the sequence $X=00000...$ will give you $[0,{1\over 3}]\cap [0,{1\over 9}]\cap [0,{1\over 27}]\cap ...=\{0\}.$

Comment: @Noah , that can't happen since X is irrational

Comment: @Zee I used $X=0000...$ as an example. The same thing will happen **regardless of what $X$ is.**

Comment: @Zee I've made an answer to address this confusion.

Comment: To give a _concrete_ construction: take a standard enumeration of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$ (first whole numbers, then halves, then thirds, etc.) and call it $q_2, q_3, \ldots$; then from rational $q_n$ take $(q_n - 2^{-n}, q_n + 2^{-n})$; then subtract all these intervals from $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **think** what you want is the set  of those $t \in [0,1]$ with base $3$ expansion $.t_1 t_2 t_3 \ldots $ (i.e. $t = \sum_{j=1}^\infty t_j 3^{-j}$) such that
$t_j \in \{0,2\}$ if $x_j = 0$ and $t_j = 1$ if $x_j = 1$, where $X = .x_1 x_2 x_3 \ldots$ is the base $2$ expansion of the irrational number $X$. That would be a correct answer.

Comment: That seems similar to what am saying, but doesn't this force the end point eventually to be irrational? Which is a contradiction

Comment: @Zee : You could intersect $[0,1]$ with a subinterval having irrational endpoints, then keep only those $t$ in this new subinterval, if you are concerned about endpoints.  Say, $t \in (\sqrt{2}-1, \sqrt{3}-1)$ with base $3$ expansion ...

Comment: What contradiction?  You asked for a subset without rationals.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Let $X_n = 2^{-n-1/2}$ for each natural $n$. Then the base-2 expansion of $X_n$ starts with $n$ zeroes, and so there is a corresponding $t_n$ with base-3 expansion starting with $n$ zeros. Thus $t_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and hence the set constructed in this answer is **not closed**.

Comment: @user21820: It works if $X$ is a _fixed_ irrational number used to construct the whole set.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Okay that was not clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: @robert Israel , I am confused since 1/3^n is rational and hence the end points at each cantor step has to be rational but I suppose eventually the appropriate segments shrink down to an irrational number. BTW your answer is the correct version of what I wanted to say so thanks.

Comment: The reason you don't get any "end points", $k/3^n$ is that the binary expansion of the irrational number $X$ has infinitely many $1$'s and infinitely many $0$'s.

Answer (score 4):

Not that you asked about it, but you can avoid the Cantor set-ternary expansion bit by considering any $U\subset [0,1],$ $U$ open in $[0,1],$ containing $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1],$ with $m(U)<1/2.$ Then $[0,1]\setminus U$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$ having measure greater than $1/2$ that contains no rational.

If you know about the regularity of Lebesgue measure, then let $E$ be the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1].$ We have $m(E)=1$ and by regularity,

$$m(E) = \sup \{ m(K): K \subset E, K \text { closed in } \mathbb R \}.$$

It follows that there are plenty of of closed subsets of $[0,1]$ having positive measure that contain only irrational numbers.

Comment: Using measure here is massive overkill, though (and also doesn't help produce an example).

Comment: Well measure theory is one of the tags, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: I didn't mean that negatively, I just meant to clarify for the OP what measure is and isn't doing in the context of this problem.

Comment: Another nonconstructive example is as follows: Take the zero set of a Brownian motion $(B_t)$ . One may show that this is almost surely a perfect set with more than one point, hence uncountable. But $$P(\exists q \in \Bbb Q: B_q=0) \leq \sum_q P(B_q=0)=0$$ Thus we have our example, which is obviously overkill.

Comment: My favorite! The whole point of non-constructive examples is to save labor, right? I'm not quite sold on the idea that constructive is "better" +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

> This subset is obviously closed and uncountable, and since we are using an irrational index all the elements of that subset will be irrational.

The word "obviously" is one you should always be afraid of in math. While it is indeed obvious that your set is closed (being an intersection of closed sets) and it's not hard to show that it consists only of irrationals (although that isn't really trivial - you should say a bit about why it's true), it is **not true** that the set is uncountable!

I explained this in the case when $X=000...$ in the comments; your response was

> that can't happen since $X$ is irrational.

However, it makes no difference what $X$ is; no matter what we pick for $X$, we'll always get a single point. In fact, it's easy to describe the point you'll get: it's just $X$ itself, but with each $1$ replaced by a $2$ and then interpreted as a ternary expansion. E.g. if we have $$X=0.010011000111...$$ your process will produce the set $$\{0.020022000222...\}.$$

*(Don't believe me? What's a **different** point in the set you get from this $X$?)*

To see why this is true, just note that at each step of the process you're determining another digit of the elements in the set you're building. E.g. with the $X$ above, by looking at the first three digits it's clear that in the set you build, every point's ternary expansion will begin "$0.020...$". So your whole process determines the point completely. **The reason the Cantor set is uncountable is that you "keep having choices"** - e.g. your first ternary digit could be $0$ *or* $2$, your second ternary digit could be $0$ *or* $2$, etc. By removing these choices as you've done, you get only one point.

Comment: Mmmmm this feels weird though, doesn't this imply the cantor set degenerates into a bunch of single points eventually?

Comment: @Zee No. It implies that the Cantor set is **made up of** single points (which is true of any set of points - that's what sets are). Each infinite binary sequence $X$ determines a single point of the Cantor set, and each point in the Cantor set corresponds to a unique infinite binary sequence. But the set of all infinite binary sequences is **huge** (by which I mean, it's uncountable). Each interval at each stage of the Cantor set construction corresponds to a finite binary string - e.g. $[{2\over 9},{1\over 3}]$ corresponds to the string "$01$" - (cont'd)

Comment: and every infinite binary string beginning with this finite string will "name" a point in this interval (e.g. the sequences $0100000...$ and $01101010101....$ both name points in the interval $[{2\over 9}, {1\over 3}]$).

Comment: if the cantor set intervals shrink to single points , then how can it be uncountable ? After all, we start with two intervals and we keep doubling , if the intervals shrink to single points , then we should have a countable infinity number of points, course you can't reach uncountable infinity just by doubling

Comment: @Zee " course you can't reach uncountable infinity just by doubling" Obvious though that may seem, it's false. If you "double infinitely many times," you do in fact get an uncountable set. (This is just Cantor's diagonal argument.)

Comment: (Of course, part of the "meat" here is making the phrase "double infinitely many times" precise. You need to be very careful when reasoning about infinite sets - basic intuitions often turn out to either be vague or incorrect.)

Comment: but how could that be true? If a countable union of countable sets is countable , how can I reach uncountablity just by doubling infinitely many times?

Comment: @Zee Because there's two different notions of "double infinitely many times" (this is what my previous comment was getting at): one is to take the *union* of the stages, while the other is to take the infinite *product* of two-element sets. The first yields a countable set, while the second yields an uncountable set, and it's the second one that's going on here. E.g. the first is describing the set of all finite binary strings (length $1$ = double once, length $2$ = double twice, etc.) while the latter is describing the set of all *infinite* binary strings. This is vague, of course (cont'd)

Comment: but so is what you're saying. The point is that using suggestive-but-imprecise language like "double infinitely many times" is a great way to mislead yourself.

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that @Zee never made clear whether he is talking about the single set $\{\text{intersection of intervals specified by }X\mid X\in\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q\}$ (which consists of irrationals and is uncountable, but is _not closed_), or he expects that _for each irrational $X$_ he will get a solution by intersecting intervals with the Cantor set. In the latter case Noah's objection applies.

Comment: @noah , thanks for the answer, it was the second best one here and you clarified important concepts for me.

Answer (score 2):

The Cantor set $C \subset [0,1]$ is an uncountable disjoint union of sets $C_x, x \in C$ that are all homomorphic to $C$ (so perfect compact etc.). There can only be a rational in countably many of the $C_x$ so lots of them contain not rationals.

The union property is direct from $C \times C \simeq C$ which can be seen from the ternary expansion representation of the Cantor set: split the expansion of $x \in C$ into an odd and even indexed part to produce a pair of points in $C$. Merging two such expansion is the inverse.

An alternative but less elementary way to see the homeomorphism is to use Brouwer's theorem that all compact totally disconnected metric spaces without isolated points are homeomorphic to (each other and to )$C$.

Comment: Are you certain that there are uncountably many copies of $C$ inside $C$? All the end points are rational, and each smaller copy of $C$ inside $C$ has an end point, right?

Comment: @Henno sir  pliz  help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383987/how-there-are-4-possible-dense-subset

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest solution to your question.
$
\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}
\def\less{\smallsetminus}
$

Let $(r_n)_{n\in\nn}$ be a sequence enumerating all the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Let $S = [0,1] \less \bigcup_{n\in\nn} B(r_n,2^{-3-n})$, where $B(r,d)$ is the open interval centred at $r$ with radius $d$.

Then $S$ is clearly closed and has measure at least $1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-2-n} = \frac12$.

Comment: This gives an explicit construction for the same idea given in [zhw.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2415667).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is explicit enough for you:

Fix $0< \epsilon < 1$. Enumerate the rationals in $[0,1]$ by $\{q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Around $q_n$ take the open ball $B(q_n, \epsilon 2^{-n})$.

Then $$[0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B(q_n, \epsilon 2^{-n})$$ satsifies the properties you want.

It is evidently closed, and it must be uncountable, since we are removing (at most) a collection of intervals of total length $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{2} <1.$$

So then we have left a set of "length" (really, "measure") greater than $1-\displaystyle \frac\epsilon2 $.

You should see that it is immediate (use the same idea I just gave) that a countable set can be covered by a countable collection of intervals of total length less than any positive number. Hence our set cannot be countable.

By construction, our set has no rationals.

**Note**: that we dealt with the rationals was inconsequential. The only property of the rationals that we needed for this construction was the fact that they are countable.