# How there are $ 4 $ possible dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Possible number of dense subset  of metric space  $X$

I found the  answer but i have  some  confusion in my  mind

[image]

My attempt : If i take two non-isolated point  that is $ p= \mathbb{Q}$ , $q=\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ where $p$ and $q$  are two non -isolated point , Then according henno  Brandsma sir   answer
Number of possible  dense subset  are

$1. c(q)$

$2.c(p)$

$3.c(p) \cap c(q)$

$4.\mathbb{R}= X$

But Here option 3  is  not possible because  $c(p) \cap c(q) = \emptyset= \mathbb{Q} \cap( \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset $

we know  that  empty set is not dense.

Then  How  there are  $4$  possible dense subset ?

Comment: Perhaps give a link to the original question?  It is not clear what your assumptions on $X$ are.

Comment: What do you mean $p=\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes no sense to me.

I am talking about points $p$ and $q$ from the space, you take subsets ? $p=\Bbb Q$?

If we're working in the reals: the reals have uncountably many different dense subsets, e.g. already all sets of the form $\Bbb R\setminus F$ where $F$ is finite (we can even take countable $F$), plus sets like the irrationals.

So we are **given** that we are in a metric space $X$ with only **finitely many** dense subsets. So for sure $X=\Bbb R$ is impossible. I give an example of a subspace $X$ of the reals that indeed has finitely many (4) dense subsets. So it is possible to have such $X$.

In the remainder of the answer I try to explain why *if* $X$ has finitely many dense subsets this number is a power of $2$ (so $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$ etc.) and that is why $4$ was the right answer to the multiple choice in the original question.

$C(p)$ is the complement of a point! Your question is based on a misunderstanding.